# Nonsensical t-value for level of mixed effect categorical predictor

Tags: mixed-model, p-value

I have a very unbalanced dataset (102 observations, 26 groups) which I am trying to fit into a mixed effects model. The predictive variables are latitude (continuous) and dominant species (categorical). The dominant species that is prevalent in most plots (52 of the observations) is coming out with an absurdly high t-value (62,232,122)... from my understanding this indicates that something with the model/dataset is not working correctly.

```
Fixed effects: C.density ~ Latitude + Genus 
            Value Std.Error DF  t-value p-value
(Intercept)  43.91762  4.645065 71        9  0.0000
Latitude     -1.64942  0.408628 71       -4  0.0001
Genusbr       2.20543  0.802307 71        3  0.0076
Genusex     -12.45166  5.596209 71       -2  0.0293
Genuska       4.99432 17.916553 24        0  0.7828
Genusrh       2.00000  0.000000 71 62232122  0.0000
Genusso       9.40151  3.436961 71        3  0.0079
```

Does anyone have any suggestions as to why this might be happening? What would produce such a high t-value for one level of a categorical factor?

Comment: The reason for the high $t$ value is because the standard error for Genusrh is essentially 0. Since $t$ is calculated as a function of 1/standard error, this will make the $t$ value shoot up. The reason the standard error is so high for that predictor could be because of the lack of enough observations to allow for variability.

Comment: I actually have more observations of that predictor than any other, though. Do you mean lack of enough observations in the total dataset?

Comment: In fact it could be due to high variability in the predictor Genusrh, since essentially $Var(\hat{\beta}) = \sigma^2/(\sum (x_i -\bar{x})^2)$.

Comment: this does look weird.  Any chance of a reproducible example?

Comment: @Ben Bolker Reproducible example would be tough -- the data is really unbalanced with a lot of variation in # of observations per group, dominant genera levels in groups (sometimes more than one), etc.@Greenparker Is there a way to confirm that?